# How to handle Incremental & Full Upload in a Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a Azure Storage Account with 2 blob stores. A Full and a Inc.
In the Full we place the full upload CSV files whenever a Full Upload is needed, in the Inc we just place day by day small incremental CSV Files.
We load all our data first in a staging, then to the ODS en finally to a Edw (Enterprise DW).
A full upload is only needed when there are structural changes to the tables.

Basically the only difference between the two uploads is that the full also cleares all data in the ODS and the EDW, but runs the sames stored procedures in the pipelines, ...

Anybody has tips on how to handle such a situation in a Azure Data Factory.
I would prefer not to double the data-factories, but due to the different avalability/frequency of the output datasets I can't use the same staging logical (in the data-factory) table as output dataset ....

So any hint(s) are appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all to be clear ADF is just there to invoke other Azure services, it doesn't do any of the work itself. So the question really is; what services in Azure could you call from ADF to do this work and manage this situation?

To answer that...

**Option 1:** I would suggest you look at Azure Data Lake. I've written simply procedures to what you've described above in USQL where parameters can be passed to the USQL procedures from ADF for different types of behaviour.

The code you create can live in an Azure Data Lake Analytics database, similar to TSQL objects. Then maybe start using Azure Data Lake Storage as well, instead of normal blobs.

**Option 2:** Break out the C# and create yourself an Azure Data Factory custom activity and create a set of classes to do exactly what you require. Again with params passed by ADF or include logic in the methods to check the 'full' table contents. This will however involve a lot more development work and require an Azure Batch Service for the compute.